# BeautifulSoup.find() is returning None, unable to access table on wiki page

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_items'_stats"
page = requests.get(url).text

pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')

table = pageSoup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
print(table)
```

I am trying to access the data from a table on a wiki page.  I have already accessed the table on another page, however the return I am getting from the find function from this page is None.  Also, when i print all p tags, there is only one p tag in the whole of the soup, which seems strange to say the least, therefore I think there might be an error in the way I am accessing the html.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there is a dynamic tab mechanism going on in the background. You should select the tab which you want and use the link for that. For example if you would like to see the Offensive tab, you can right click and open the corresponding page, which will give you the correct url, then with this your code is running correctly:

```
url = 'http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_items%27_stats/Offensive'
```

Comment: Ah worked like a charm.  Thank you very much.  I'm a bit lost when it comes to anything more than basic webpages, I'll have to try and learn more on that to improve my scripts.  Thanks again.